# Compatible activeadmin and activeadmin_mongoid gem with rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, activeadmin

How do I set up active admin with mongodb. My gem file includes following gem:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0' 
...
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources', branch: 'rails-4-2'
gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', github: 'elia/activeadmin-mongoid', branch: 'rails4'
```

All working fine but I am getting this error.

```
Showing /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@gemset/bundler/gems/activeadmin-7aef260921d4/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `column_for_attribute' for #<SuperAdmin:0x00000006a98c78>
```

[image: NoMethodError in Admin::SuperAdmins#index]

How do I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with rails 4.2 support at the moment.

I experienced the same issue after upgrading to 4.2: `Undefined method column_for_attribute`

I eventually came across https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid/issues/95 which lead me to this pull request https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid/pull/96/files

So I tried using:

`gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', github: 'pencilcheck/activeadmin-mongoid', branch: 'patch-1'`

in my Gemfile, which fixed my first error, but then raised another error about `_ransack` not being available. So I looked at the pull request again, and tried re-adding what @pencilcheck removed:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Filters
    module FormtasticAddons

      # The resource class, unwrapped from Ransack
      def klass
        @object.klass
      end

    end
  end
end
```

After adding this in to one of my models, everything works again!

I've submitted an issue about this: https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid/issues/97